# App Crash due to Urban Airship Implementation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com

I am having an app in which I am using Urban Airship For Push notification.

I integrated the latest SDK for it.

**My configuration plist is as follow:**

APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD = YES

In Production (resolved): 1

In Production (as set): 1

Development App Key:

Development App Secret:

Production App Key: XXXXXXXX

Production App Secret: XXXXXXXX

Development Log Level: 4

Production Log Level: 1

Resolved Log Level: 1

Detect Provisioning Mode: 0

Clear Keychain: 0

Analytics Enabled: 1

Analytics URL: https://combine.urbanairship.com

Device API URL: https://device-api.urbanairship.com

**But my app is crashed on following line**

```
[UAirship takeOff:config];
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A stack trace would be very useful here ...

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922547/1637562.

Make sure you add "-ObjC" flag to "Other Linker Flags" in your build settings.