# Urban Airship crashes when calling takeoff

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, urbanairship.com, nsjsonserialization

Upgrading to UrbanAirship 3.0.0 with Xcode 5.0, I'm getting an error when calling this code:

```
[UAirship takeOff:config];
```

The error is

```
+[NSJSONSerialization stringWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b2ca9fc
2013-09-19 15:02:31.981 [178:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSJSONSerialization stringWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3b2ca9fc'
```

This doesn't seem to appear when setting the key "inProduction" to "YES" in the `AirshipConfig.plist`, which makes sense as calling takeOff: populates the instance of UAirShip.
It seems to be due to the category `NSJSONSerialization+UAAdditions`.

Any help on this one?
Thanks

Comment: Whats the value/type for 'config'?

Comment: I'm setting a default config `UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];`

Comment: Same problem here, any idea?

Comment: Check the value of config?

Comment: Just posted my solution which seems to work fine. Ask me if you have any problem regarding how I've done it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix this issue, you must include "-ObjC" flag in "Other Linker Flags" found in your projects build settings.

UAirship library 3.x now makes use of Objective-C categories so this flag must be set to avoid the runtime exception.

Details on the issue can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Updated the docs:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#build-settings
http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic_guides/ios_migration.html#linker-flags

Comment: Awesome, had this upgrading to 5.0.3 in XCode 6, worked fine one day and then the next it was crashing... very strange but adding the linker flag worked!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seam to be happening with the source: https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library

Comment: I'm using the source and carefully followed the UrbanAirship's tutorial found here http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You must have included both the libraries:

- libUAirship-3.0.0.a
- libUAirship-iOS5-3.0.0.a

You have to use either of the library for respective iOS

Comment: Actually, I've only added the library `libUAirship-iOS5-3.0.0`
I'm running my app with iOS Deployment Target - iOS 5.0 and Base SDK is iOS 7.0

Answer (score 0):

After looking at different solutions, it turns out that this fixes the issue:

• Download sources from https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library directly into your App folder (don't take .zip given on their website)

• Drag & drop the Airship folder in your Project (do not use the AirshipLib one)

• **Don't** link any of the `libUAirship-3.0.0.a` or `libUAirship-iOS5-3.0.0.a`

• Boom. It's working.

Hope it'll help some others out there looking to fix this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, my problem was that I added `-ObjC` flag to the `project`, and it should be added to the `target` settings.

Also, if that does not compile, there is another option

```
-Wl,-force_load,<PathToYourLib>/libUAirship-4.0.0.a
```

Also should be added to the target. Fill the real path to your lib instead of `<PathToYourLib>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using **cocoapods** and **Xcode 15**,
add/update this in your Podfile to

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```